# Working with wifi or bluetooth document scanner in Phonegap

Tags: cordova, bluetooth, visual-studio-cordova

We are tasked with developing an Android app that will receive documents scanned by a bluetooth or wifi enabled portable document scanner. There is no wifi infrastructure where the scanner will be deployed. What I'd need to do is find a scanner with an API reference I can use to get the scanned documents into the app and then process as needed.

Is there such a device that you know of? I have found a couple with a free bundled app, but I need to know HOW that app communicates so that I can build my own. And that's where my problem lies: the missing API reference.

Comment: "Working with wife" => "Working with WiFi", I guess? :p

Comment: What's the difference?

Comment: I remembered one slogans at one restaurant in China: "We provide free wife "; it is actually means "we provide free wifi"

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you using Bluetooth SPP or Wi-Fi P2P to transport scanned document; for Bluetooth SPP profile the speed may slow; it is possible to using P2P, it is convenience for you to transport document or pictures.

P2P :
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html#transferring

SPP:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html#ConnectingDevices